# LIMIT rows by column in a SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, limit

Using the LIMIT clause to reduce the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement; i only wanted to tie the LIMIT clause to a column value that contains INT.

```
Select *
FROM customer.questions, customer.answers, customer.counts 
WHERE customer.question qid = customer.answers qid AND
      customer.questions q_type = customer.counts q_type
ORDER BY customer.counts limit DESC LIMIT colname
```

PROBLEM:
Using LIMIT with column value; my customer.counts limit INT is colname containing value like 20.

Note:
 QID (AI) INT

QID (FK) INT from customer.questions table

Q_TYPE (FK) INT from customer.questions table

Comment: You should decide which database you are using and tag the question appropriately.  SQL Server and MySQL are different databases.

Comment: And you should use ANSI-92 style joins instead of the older ANSI-89 style. They are much easier to read and less prone to error.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to limit the number of rows returned using the value of a column? And please refine your query because it doesn't seem to be a valid query (e.g. ORDER BY LIMIT is invalid, column names in where conditions are not well-formed).

Comment: yea, i have it corrected already, and any way i have a PR system,i intend to limit article to let say 50 per day